# Is there any way to retrieve display brightness and light sensor value of iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, sensors, brightness

Is there any way to retrieve display brightness and light sensor value of iPhone?

Suppose i have a jailbroken iPhone.
Either command line of ssh or object-C code are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Located in private BackBoardServices.framework:

```
float BKSDisplayBrightnessGetCurrent();
```

As for light sensor, couldn't find any methods to retrieve it's value. There're only three methods: check for existance of the sensor, enable/disable auto-brightness.

Comment: Excellent! That's what i want. As for light sensor, it doesn't make sense, because there are some app such as sleep monitor which can detect if turn iPhone up side down

Comment: You can detect that using device orientation UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown

Answer (score 0):

A common workaround for getting an approximation of the light sensor value is through:

`NSLog(@"Screen Brightness: %f",[[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness]);`

But there is no API to access the ambient light sensor directly.